# AngularJS unit testing dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I need to make unit tests in AngularJS project, I've never done it before and I got a problems in first step.

Packages:

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
"karma": "^1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0"
```

Controller (as syntax):

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginController', ['models.store', function(MODELS) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.account = new MODELS.Account('', '');
}]);
```

So I need to write a test for this controller property - *account*

Test:

```
describe('LoginTest', function() {
    var MODELS;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        inject(function() {
            MODELS = jasmine.createSpy('models.store');
        });
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        scope = $controller('LoginController', {'models.store': MODELS});
    }));

    it('Account model values should be empty', function() {
        expect(scope.account.login).toBe('');
    });
});
```

And I get **"TypeError: MODELS.Account is not a constructor"**

Injecting factory code:

```
angular.module('app.models').factory('models.store', function() {
    return {
        Account: function() {
            this.login = login || '';
            this.password = password || '';
        }
    }
});
```

What do I do wrong? What should I do to make the test correct?

Comment: There are two ways (as almost always) - first one - you can stub Models and create spy on method `Account`, second way - you can inject `models.store` and then spy

Comment: I thought all controller dependencies will imported automatically. Obviously not. The way to describe each dependency is huge. In particular that controller have six ones. Just for testing a simple value! Awfully

Answer (score 0):

The very first iteration can look like that:

```js
angular.module('app', ['app.models'])

angular.module('app').controller('LoginController', ['store', function(MODELS) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.account = new MODELS.Account('', '');
}]);

angular.module('app.models', [])

angular.module('app.models').factory('store', function() {
  return {
    Account: function(login, password) {
      this.login = login || '';
      this.password = password || '';
    }
  }
});

describe('LoginTest', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, store) {
    scope = $controller('LoginController', {
      'store': store
    });
  }));

  it('Account model values should be empty', function() {
    expect(scope.account.login).toBe('');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/boot.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Another approach can be described as

```js
angular.module('app', ['app.models'])

angular.module('app').controller('LoginController', ['store', function(MODELS) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.account = new MODELS.Account('', '');
}]);

angular.module('app.models', [])

describe('LoginTest', function() {
  var stubStore

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    stubStore = {
      Account: jasmine.createSpy()
    }
  })

  beforeEach(function() {
    stubStore.Account
  })

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    scope = $controller('LoginController', {
      'store': stubStore
    });
  }));

  it('Account model values should be empty', function() {
    expect(stubStore.Account).toHaveBeenCalledWith('', '')
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/jasmine-html.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.8.0/boot.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have an error still:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=storeProvider%20%3C-%20store
And scope is undefined

Comment: Have you executed `run code snippet`? Is is works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!

The only successful way were:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    var scope, MODELS;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        MODELS = $injector.get('models.store');
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
        scope = $controller('LoginController', {});
    }));

    it('Expect Account model Login is empty', function () {
        expect(scope.account.login).toBe('');
    });
});
```